# How to get system privilege

Tags: c#, system, uefi, privilege

I have a C# program that require `SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege` to access the `UEFI NVRAM`.

I found a really long code, that uses `Win32 API` to get the privilege, but is there a .NET version to get it? In process class, or somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know if it will work or not, so posting as a comment, but try using [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) with the `-s -i` switches, that will run a interactive program as the SYSTEM user. `PsExec.exe -s -i YourApp.exe`

Answer (score 4):

If it is really necessary you can use the *AdjustTokenPrivileges* function. 
Something like this:

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
    ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);
```

You can get more info here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375728(v=vs.85).aspx#privilege_constants